# Quiz App in objective C

Tags: objective-c, database

I am developing a quiz app in objective C (being specific to language only in objective C).

This is my database structure:

[image: Database Structure]

This is my data in database:

[image: here]

my question is when i press the NEXT button in my app interface, it should display the 2nd question in the view controller and its corresponding options, and so on. 
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: This is the app interface:

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: see my ans and let me know .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method which enumerate questions according to their `ids` like `1, 2 , 3 ..so on` see example below:

```
// create global variable
int quesId = 1;

-(IBAction)nextQuestion:(id)sender{

    // clear all the ui components like uitextfield or label before you load next ques

    // check before you fetch ques using its id if present or not and take appropriate action

    // fetch ques using quesId (run you code to fetch ques from db)

    // increment everytime quesId to fetch next ques accordingly
    if(quesId < recordAry.count){
        quesId +=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome just click on the accept button(right tick) below down vote button .. :)

Comment: when all the elements are called from database, the app terminates by saying:


2016-09-23 00:52:55.021 NewQuiz[11807:51264] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (4) beyond bounds (4)'
as i have 4 entries in my database.

Now when all my entries are called and my app reaches its last question and after I press the button I should get a notification..
how can I do that?

Comment: @GauravKapur `NSRangeException` came when you try to access an array index is greater > then its count just double check you array access while fetching records ..secondly just count no of record and check before you increase the `quesId` until it is less then db record see updated ans ..